# Pass data from parent to child and sibling children using context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display fetched data in child component, using context api. But I'm getting below error on browser

> TypeError: render is not a function
>   The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in AppDataList (at App.js:32)
>       in div (at App.js:30)
>       in App (at src/index.js:7)

and below warning

> Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children, or a
>   child that isn't a function. A context consumer expects a single child
>   that is a function. If you did pass a function, make sure there is no
>   trailing or leading whitespace around it.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import AppDataList from "./components/AppDataList";
export const AppContext = React.createContext();

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      appData: []
    };
  }

  fetchAppData() {
    fetch(` http://localhost:4000/AppDataList`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({
          appData: res
        });
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchAppData();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppContext.Provider>
          <AppDataList />
        </AppContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**AppDataList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../App";

export default class AppDataList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        <div>{context => <p>{context.state}</p>}</div>
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

I also want to do something like

```
<AppContext.Provider>
   <Child1 />
   <Child2 />
   <Child3 />
 </AppContext.Provider>
```

and consume data in respective child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below works:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {context => <p>{context.state}</p>}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

consumer looks for function, not component.
ref: [Seeing "render is not a function" when trying to use Context API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571818/seeing-render-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-context-api/56572733)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the value you want to pass to Consumers via the value prop in the Provider:

```
<Context.Provider value={{ appData }}>
```

Comment: tried <AppContext.Provider value={{ appData }}> says "appData not defined."

also tried         <AppContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
says "Uncaught TypeError: render is not a function"

Comment: Since you're using a class component your state is accessible via this.state, so try this: value={{ appData: this.state.appData }}

That should be accessible in the render function as value.appData, e.g. 
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */ value.appData}

Comment: I have tried this too, it gives warning "index.js:1 Warning: A context consumer was rendered with multiple children" and error "Uncaught TypeError: render is not a function" and error "index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component". is it something to do with any "type" as the error mentions?