# TypeError: render is not a function while using React Context along with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I need to set up a user state that can be called from different components. This setup uses React Router and React Context.
The React context contains just a single state that keeps track of the user's name.

At the top-level i.e App I have passed all the children on to the provider. But I get an error

`TypeError: render is not a function`

**My UserContext code:**

```
const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContext;
```

**My App code :**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/register" component={UserRegister} />
            <Route path="/homepage/:user" component={Homepage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The entrie error log:

```
TypeError: render is not a function
updateContextConsumer
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18747
  18744 | {
  18745 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
  18746 |   setIsRendering(true);
> 18747 |   newChildren = render(newValue);
        | ^  18748 |   setIsRendering(false);
  18749 | } // React DevTools reads this flag.
  18750 | 
View compiled
beginWork
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19114
  19111 |   return updateContextProvider(current, workInProgress, renderLanes);
  19112 | 
  19113 | case ContextConsumer:
> 19114 |   return updateContextConsumer(current, workInProgress, renderLanes);
        | ^  19115 | 
  19116 | case MemoComponent:
  19117 |   {
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945
  3942 | function callCallback() {
  3943 |   didCall = true;
  3944 |   restoreAfterDispatch();
> 3945 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
       | ^  3946 |   didError = false;
  3947 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  3948 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994
  3991 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  3992 | 
  3993 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 3994 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
       | ^  3995 | 
  3996 | if (windowEventDescriptor) {
  3997 |   Object.defineProperty(window, 'event', windowEventDescriptor);
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056
  4053 | function invokeGuardedCallback(name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  4054 |   hasError = false;
  4055 |   caughtError = null;
> 4056 |   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl$1.apply(reporter, arguments);
  4057 | }
  4058 | /**
  4059 |  * Same as invokeGuardedCallback, but instead of returning an error, it stores
View compiled
beginWork$1
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964
  23961 | } // Run beginWork again.
  23962 | 
  23963 | 
> 23964 | invokeGuardedCallback(null, beginWork, null, current, unitOfWork, lanes);
        | ^  23965 | 
  23966 | if (hasCaughtError()) {
  23967 |   var replayError = clearCaughtError(); // `invokeGuardedCallback` sometimes sets an expando `_suppressLogging`.
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22776
  22773 | 
  22774 | if ( (unitOfWork.mode & ProfileMode) !== NoMode) {
  22775 |   startProfilerTimer(unitOfWork);
> 22776 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, subtreeRenderLanes);
        | ^  22777 |   stopProfilerTimerIfRunningAndRecordDelta(unitOfWork, true);
  22778 | } else {
  22779 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, subtreeRenderLanes);
View compiled
workLoopSync
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707
  22704 | function workLoopSync() {
  22705 |   // Already timed out, so perform work without checking if we need to yield.
  22706 |   while (workInProgress !== null) {
> 22707 |     performUnitOfWork(workInProgress);
  22708 |   }
  22709 | }
  22710 | 
View compiled
renderRootSync
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670
  22667 | 
  22668 | do {
  22669 |   try {
> 22670 |     workLoopSync();
        | ^  22671 |     break;
  22672 |   } catch (thrownValue) {
  22673 |     handleError(root, thrownValue);
View compiled
performSyncWorkOnRoot
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293
  22290 |   }
  22291 | } else {
  22292 |   lanes = getNextLanes(root, NoLanes);
> 22293 |   exitStatus = renderRootSync(root, lanes);
        | ^  22294 | }
  22295 | 
  22296 | if (root.tag !== LegacyRoot && exitStatus === RootErrored) {
View compiled
scheduleUpdateOnFiber
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881
  21878 |   // root inside of batchedUpdates should be synchronous, but layout updates
  21879 |   // should be deferred until the end of the batch.
  21880 | 
> 21881 |   performSyncWorkOnRoot(root);
        | ^  21882 | } else {
  21883 |   ensureRootIsScheduled(root, eventTime);
  21884 |   schedulePendingInteractions(root, lane);
View compiled
updateContainer
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482
  25479 |   }
  25480 | 
  25481 |   enqueueUpdate(current$1, update);
> 25482 |   scheduleUpdateOnFiber(current$1, lane, eventTime);
  25483 |   return lane;
  25484 | }
  25485 | function getPublicRootInstance(container) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021
  26018 | 
  26019 | 
  26020 |   unbatchedUpdates(function () {
> 26021 |     updateContainer(children, fiberRoot, parentComponent, callback);
        | ^  26022 |   });
  26023 | } else {
  26024 |   fiberRoot = root._internalRoot;
View compiled
unbatchedUpdates
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431
  22428 | executionContext |= LegacyUnbatchedContext;
  22429 | 
  22430 | try {
> 22431 |   return fn(a);
        | ^  22432 | } finally {
  22433 |   executionContext = prevExecutionContext;
  22434 | 
View compiled
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020
  26017 |   } // Initial mount should not be batched.
  26018 | 
  26019 | 
> 26020 |   unbatchedUpdates(function () {
        | ^  26021 |     updateContainer(children, fiberRoot, parentComponent, callback);
  26022 |   });
  26023 | } else {
View compiled
render
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103
  26100 |     }
  26101 |   }
  26102 | 
> 26103 |   return legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, false, callback);
  26104 | }
  26105 | function unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, element, containerNode, callback) {
  26106 |   if (!isValidContainer(containerNode)) {
View compiled
Module.<anonymous>
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/src/index.js:6
  3 | import "./index.css";
  4 | import App from "./App";
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(
  7 |   <React.StrictMode>
  8 |     <App />
  9 |   </React.StrictMode>,
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1581:30
__webpack_require__
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1595:18
__webpack_require__
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
G:/WebDevelopmentFolder/trinkerrchallenge/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

Comment: Refer this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571818/seeing-render-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-context-api/56572733

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the shared code snippets. Can you update your question to include the error message in its entirety along with the stacktrace so we can see the line of code that is being blamed and what was called/mounted up to this point?

Comment: @BeaterHey That link dint help :(

Comment: How are you importing your UserProvider ? . I doubt whether you are using named import for it . Because you are exporting the UserContext by default .

Comment: @DrewReese I have added the full error log.

Comment: @Shyam Thanks a lot man ! Yeah i did forget to add { } for default imports. Thanks man! Saved my day :)